# .NET for Windows Store Apps: UrlEncode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, url-encoding

In some Windows Store App I need send URL like

```
new Uri(string.Format(@"http://www.site.com?word={0}",
                                      sourceText))
```

, where `sourceText` is the escaped representation of some text. It would be easy, if I need UTF-8, but I need Windows-1251 encoding.

I have tried

```
    byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(sourceText);
    byte[] win1251bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"), unicodeBytes);
    string sourceText =
        Uri.EscapeUriString(Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetString(win1251bytes, 0, win1251bytes.Length));
```

but `Uri.EscapeUriString` use `string`, which converting to Unicode automatically.

I could use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(word, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)`, but there is no `System.Web.HttpUtility` in .NET for Windows Store.

For example, 'привет' in UTF-8: `%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`;
                     in Windows-1251 : `%EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2`.  I need second string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sourceText = "привет";
byte[] win1251bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetBytes(sourceText);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(win1251bytes);
string result = "%" + hex.Replace("-", "%");
// Result: %EF%F0%E8%E2%E5%F2
```

Answer (score 6):

How about `WebUtility.UrlEncode`?

It lives in the System.Net namespace, more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx